# How can i run a Coded UI Test running at the same time the project in localhost that i want to test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

I'm trying to run an asp net mvc project first and then run a codedUI but do not have the option to run when the asp net project is already running
[image: Execute Tests is disabled]

Answer (score 0):

If you're running http://localhost:**port#**/index.html that's running using IIS Express via Visual Studio.

If you create a virtual directory/application you can run the website independent of Visual Studio. Setup an IIS Application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx and run your coded ui tests on: http://localhost/alias/index.html